# MYSQL Date and Time not filtering properly when use group by function

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL. When I execute a query from order by date and time in descending order it gives wrong result.  I used group by and order by and same time. Here I added some sample dataset for refer.

In below I added logs table dataset(One dataset belongs to the vehicle).

[image]

In below I added the result after executing the query.

[image]

In below I added execute query.

```
select * 
from asset_vehicle_logs 
where (description ='Vehicle verified' or description ='Vehicle rejected' or description ='Valuation details accepted') 
group by id 
order by date_log desc,time_log desc;
```

What I need?

I need to filter descriptions based on the 'Vehicle verified', 'Vehicle rejected' and 'Valuation details accepted' within the added date and time with group by ID. some logs contains above three descriptions in same date but different time. I want to filter the latest one only from above descriptions and group by ID column(Because ID act as a foreign key of vehicle table). When consider the above dataset I want to get the actual output like this.

[image]

DB Structure

```
 ID_PK - act as a primary key(UUID)
 ID    - act as a foreign key of vehicle table(Here I didn't added vehicle table because that doesnt need for this query.)
```

Comment: *What I need?* You need to study the grouping. Your `id` column contains duplicates. Each row contains its own date value. You use `GROUP BY id`, all rows are collapsed into one row. But what ONE date value from all existing ones should be used? The server does not know, you have not defined this, and the server uses one indefinitely selected value which results in "incorrect" ordering. You'd use aggregated date value, for example, `ORDER BY MAX(TIMESTAMP(date_log, time_log)) DESC`. PS. Dividing the datetime value to separate parts is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try `MAX` function in MySql

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    MAX(date_log) AS max_date
FROM
    asset_vehicle_logs a
WHERE
    description IN (
        'Vehicle verified',
        'Vehicle rejected',
        'Valuation details accepted'
    )
GROUP BY
    id;
```

This sql will return the latest date of the same id, because your date and time are separated, so you need to join the `date_log` and `time_log` into one field, and then do the same query with MAX() function.